# Hiding inaccessible links in Jinja2 templates

Tags: python, web, permissions, flask, jinja2

We're writing a web application in Flask + Jinja2 at work. 
The application has registered users which can access certain pages based on their roles. In order to achieve this on the server side we just use decorate the pages:

```
@app.route('/action1')
@security_requirements(roles=['some_role'])
def action1():
    ...
```

The decorator checks if the logged on user has 'some_role' in its role list and decides whether to pass the call to the decorated function or just redirect the user to the "access denied" page.

The application also has a navigation bar implemented using bootstrap. The navigation bar is displayed in each page using a base template. As for now, every page in the application has an entry in the navigation bar, regardless if the current user can access it or not. Despite the fact that this is not a security hole, I would like to hide from users pages which they cannot access. Furthermore, I would like to achieve this functionality without duplicating the allowed roles lists inside the Jinja templates. Is it possible to achieve this functionality in Jinja somehow by using my current decorator?

Comment: is `security_requirements` your decorator? is it permited to change it?

Comment: @twil - Yes, it is mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the `security_requirements` decorator to look like this:

```
def security_requirements(logged_in=True,
                          roles=None):
def wrapper(f):
    # Store the security attributes as a member of the function object
    f.access_control = dict(logged_in=logged_in, roles=roles)
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        access_result = _eval_access(logged_in, roles)
        # Redirect the user to the appropriate page (Access denied / Login Required / Actual Page) based on the result
        ...
```

The only real difference from the previous version of this decorator is the line that stores the security attributes inside the function object. This line is useless from inside the decorator. However, now I can implement the following action to be called from the Jinja template:

```
{% if can_access(func) %}
<li><a>...</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

The can_access function is defined in the Flask application module. It receives a string which it must convert to a function object. It does that by calling `app.view_functions`:

```
def can_access(func):
    return auth.can_access(app.view_functions[func])
```

This function should be called directly from a Jinja template. So it needs to be added to Jinja's globals:

```
app.jinja_env.globals.update(can_access=can_access)
```

Finally, `auth.can_access`:

```
def can_access(f):
    if not hasattr(f, 'access_control'):
        return True

    # Use the access_control member set by the decorator
    return _eval_access(**f.access_control) == AccessResult.ALLOWED
```

This solution means that the access control is defined in a single place - which is the function decorator.

Comment: I don't fully understand this but, nice!

Comment: You should submit this as a patch, it would be a great feature to have.

Comment: I was told the Python ecosystem has pip libraries for every kinds of needs, yet I find myself every day having to implement basic functionalities like this. Nice work, you really should take on Flask-Security or Flask-Principal and submit this.

Answer (score 8):

I use [Flask-Security](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/), which ties a lot of the login/security modules together in a nice package.  It comes with role management courtesy of Flask-Principal, which will allow you to do:

```
{% if current_user.has_role('admin') %}
    <li><a href="#">Manage Site</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

You can [see how that's implemented in the source](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/7808870fcdda68302adfcc1497a4f58b98073065/flask_security/core.py#L267), the `current_user` proxy comes from [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.current_user)

Comment: I would like to use a single place to store the list of roles allowed for each action. If I understand correctly, even with Flask-Security I would have to write two lists for each action - in the server side code and also inside the template.

Comment: So you're aiming to do something like : `{% if current_user.can_access(url_for('protected_endpoint')) %} ADMIN ONLY {% endif %}` ?

Comment: What would be ideal would be to extend flask's `url_map` itself, and actually hold permission information in there, so when you actually define an app.route you could specify the roles there, eg:

 `@app.route('/', methods=['post','get'], roles=['admin'])`. 
Which would be much nicer to use and easy to look up against from jinja2 by looking at the url_map.  It's an interesting problem, I'll have a look into it when I get some free hours.

Comment: For a potentially easier solution (but not as pretty) you could create a store that links endpoints to roles.  Then instead of specifying the roles in your decorator, it instead just looks it up against the datastore.  And your jinja2 template filter could do the same (current_user.roles vs. what the datastore is listing as required roles).